# C Shell Substring Compare

Tags: linux, unix, awk, string-comparison, csh

My data looks like the following:

```
1xxxxxx file_name1
0xxxxxx file_name2
0xxxxxx file_name3
0xxxxxx file_name4
1xxxxxx file_name5
0xxxxxx file_name6
```

I would like to print only the file names with the first column starting with a '1'.

That is,

```
awk '{if($1 contains '1') then print $2}' file.txt
```

However, I haven't a clue how to achieve the comparison syntax

Perhaps a wildcard method might be possible?

```
awk '{if($1 == "1"*) then print $2}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
awk '$1~/^1/{print $2}' file.txt
```

You check the first column (`$1`) using a `match operator` (`~`) against pattern which looks for line starting with `1` (`/^1/`). If it is true, the action of printing second column takes place.

Comment: **Code Golf:** `awk '$1~/^1/&&$0=$2' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I’d use `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep ^1 data_file | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jayplas code, this can even be shorten more:

```
awk '/^1/&&$0=$2' file
file_name1
file_name5
```

Testing for first character in `$1`, would be the same as first character of the string `$0`